# Finding an exponential equation with 2 points

Tags: exponential-function

If you have two points, for example, (2, 6) and (3, 18), how do you find the equation if you know its exponential?

I've heard about y=ab^x but I'm not sure what those variables represent.

Comment: Write $f(2)=6, f(3)=18$. If you know $f(x)=a\,b^x$ then solve the two equations for $a,b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two points on the curve to determine the two parameters $a,b$ so plug them in, giving $6=ab^2, 18=ab^3$ Can you find $a,b?$

Comment: Thanks so much, I solved and got f(x)=2/3(3^x). The way I solved was kind of long and tedious and I think there is a more efficient way. Could you explain how you would've solved for a and b?

Comment: To start, "divide the equations" like so: $ \frac{18=ab^3}{6=ab^2} \implies 3=b $.

Answer (score 0):

A linear function is one which increases (or decreases) by the same amount every time the input is increased by a unit.  For example, if $f$ is linear and $f(3)=5$ and $f(4)=10$, then you know that $f(5)=15$ and $f(6)=20$.  More generally, the slope of this function would be 5, and you could write the equation $f(x)=mx+b$ where $m=5$ and $b=-10$.

An exponential function is similar, except that the function increases or decreases by a fixed *ratio* for each increment.  If $g$ is exponential, and $g(3)=5$ and $g(4)=10$, then you would know that $g(5)=20$ and $g(6)=40$.  The general form for an exponential function is $g(x)=ab^x$, where $a$ is the intercept (note that $g(0)=a$) and $b$ is the ratio term. In this case, we have $g(x)=\frac{5}{8}\cdot 2^x$.

In your example, the function increases by a factor of $\frac{18}{6}=3$ as the input goes from $x=2$ to $x=3$.  So the ratio term is $3$, and the function has the form $g(x)=a\cdot 3^x$.  You should be able to find $a$ from here.

Answer (score 0):

Both these answers assume the form `f(x) = ab^x`; however, this presumes that the exponential function has an asymptote at `x=0`; it also assumes that base is important, but b can always be converted to `e`. Now you can also solve this problem with the more general `f(x) = ae^x + c`, which is still exponential, but now leaves the asymptote open to other possibilities and uses the natural base. This is useful for modeling a variety of phenomena, which are asymptotic at some max or min other than 0.

In this case, given `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`:

```
f(x1) = y1 = ae^x1 + c
f(x2) = y2 = ae^x2 + c
```

To solve for `a` subtract c from the first equation and divide by everything left over not a. You should get:

```
a = (y1-c)/e^(x1 * x) (see expression for x below)
```

To solve for x subtract c from both equations and divide one equation by the other, and then use the natural log. Like any sloppy mathematician, out of laziness, I leave this exercise to the reader or some future enterprising person who wants to type the steps of that piece out. However, you should get:

```
x = ln((y2-c)/(y1-c))/(x2-x1)
```